# Dock like Shortcuts

Tags: c#

I'm looking to develop a program which allows users to drag their desktop shortcuts onto a dock / slideout bar on the desktop. How can i make it possible for a 'Desktop Shortcut' to be dragged onto the Dock to create a Shortcut there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the properties editor for your drop target (component or form) and set `AllowDrop` to `true`.  Then create event handlers for the DragEnter and DragDrop events:

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] asFormats = e.Data.GetFormats();
    string[] asFileNames = (string[])e.Data.GetData("FileName");
}
```

This will give you the file name that was dropped on your target.  From there it's up to you to parse the .LNK file.